# SSRS Multiple tool tips

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, tooltip, reporting-services

Does anyone know if its possible to have multiple tool tips displayed when you hover your cursor over a chart.

e.g currently my barchart displays a project name, I want it to also display the Department Service when you hover over below the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
="Project: " + Fields!barname.Value + VbCrLf  + "Service: " + Fields!SERVICE.Value
```

Adding in `vbCrLf` between fields creates a 'return' and gives 2 seperate fields in 1 tooltip

Answer (score 0):

No.
Why not put all the info into the one tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different tool tips for different data elements on the chart, and then a defaalt tooltip for hovering over other chart areas. Use Expressions to combineother data fields into your tooltip, and add newlines as needed.

These are set up as the "Tooltip" of the Series Properties.

Answer (score 0):

**="Value: "&Sum(Fields!Field_1.Value) & " Year: 2012" &  " Customer: Test"**

Above Worked fine! You can pass also the dynamic value from fields for year and customer...